# Linux incoming XRDP connection locks local login until reboot

Tags: xrdp, almalinux

I have a machine running Almalinux. I can remotely connect to it via XRDP (windows client). However, after disconnecting, it's impossible for someone sitting at the machine to login until they reboot the machine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: How are you disconnecting from XRDP? See if [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326143/local-ubuntu-desktop-cannot-login-after-logging-in-remotely-via-xrdp-session) solves the problem. If it does, I'll put up an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem. The cause is the resolution.

If you login at the machine using a resolution, you can only RDP into that session using the same resolution and bit depth. Because the monitor attached to my server is not too big, I don't want to have a small resolution.

In the same way, if you RDP into the server with a preset resolution, you can login locally only with that resolution too.

For me, this essentially meant that xdrp was out of the question, also because I need my user to remain logged in to keep my vm up and running (somehow can't set it to a service).

My solution was to use a VNC server and connect to different sessions that way. I also have a local viewer user that can do TightVNC locally to connect to a session that way (although that is not necessary if you login locally first, and then connect with VNC.

Comment: thanks, let me try that. I thought all my screens were the same (4k) but maybe the bit depth is different.

Comment: If you RDP into a server, the GUI may be cut off and give you a weird resolution. For example, 1920x1080 can become 1914x1036, and yes, bit dept is as important. Basically, every time the screenmode changes (different resolution, or mode) it will not accept it as the same connection. This is just a bad implementation of xRDP to VNC and is not a problem if you go VNC natively.